# Jekyll custom theme (running locally)

Tags: jekyll, jekyll-theme

I'm new to Jekyll and I am trying to get a custom theme up and running. Here's is what I've done so far:

1. Created my Jekyll site. CD to the directory I wanted to install it and ran

   `bundle exec jekyll serve`

These files were created and I was able to see the site locally at the default 4000 port.

[image]

I then tried following the instructions [here](https://www.siteleaf.com/blog/making-your-first-jekyll-theme-part-2/) for installing your own theme. I entered this in my terminal:

```
$ jekyll new-theme skull_and_roses
```

As the instructions indicated it built out a new directory...

[image]

It also added a directory in the _site directory, not sure if that is correct:

[image]

I then followed these instructions:

[image]

But when I go to run it:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --watch
```

I get an error:

```
The skull_and_roses theme could not be found.
```

Like I said, this is my first run at Jekyll so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `jekyll new-theme skull_and_roses` created a new jekyll instance inside the `skull_and_roses` folder. What the document says is that you should create an index inside that folder and run jekyll from that directory to test it. To create a new theme, just create your layout files inside `_layouts` and make sure that your posts uses them.

Answer (score 5):

I also use [jekyll theme template](https://github.com/kitian616/jekyll-TeXt-theme) (It is a nice template with friendly manual) and customize it to set up [my own github page](https://xiaoyanzhuo.github.io) recently.

Beside create repo on github use username (`username.github.io`), What I did on my mac (locally) are:

1. set up env for using Jekyll, you can reference: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/
2. `$ git clone https://github.com/username/username.github.io.git` (assuming you have already create the repo).
3. `$ cd username.github.io`
4. `$ git clone <theme github repo>`
5. put all the theme files into the root of your website files (dir we create in step2)
6. usually the theme template will have `Gemfile`, if really not, you can try to create Gemfile and type in:

   ```
   source 'https://rubygems.org'
   gem 'github-pages', group: :jekyll_plugins
   ```

   After you confirm you have `Gemfile`, Run

   ```
   $ bundle install 
   $ bundle exec jekyll serve
   ```

   Now, you can enter `localhost:4000` or `127.0.0.1:4000` to check the theme can run on local serve.
7. Then you can mainly modify `_config.yml` file, like title, author, and other from the theme template instructions. You can check it locally(`localhost:4000` or `127.0.0.1:4000`) whenever you update something and you want to check the result. Usually changing in `_config.yml`, you need to restart the `jekyll serve` (using `ctrl+c` to stop and run `$ bundle exec jekyll serve` to restart the service to check the modification. You may need to modify more than `_config.yml` file to meet your own requirement, at least like `about.md` or add your own posts in `_post`.
8. After you finish modification from theme template and make your own github page you like. You can push the local repo to remote repo (master branch of `username.github.io`). Btw, if you work locally, you can use branch to test features you want to add, checking result locally and then merge to master when you are satisfied with the result.
9. Finally, you can check: `https://username.github.io` and enjoy your own github page.
10. For your question about `_site` and other things you may want to know, you may also want to check followings:

    [Creating and Hosting a Personal Site on GitHub](http://jmcglone.com/guides/github-pages/)

    [Quick start & tutorials on jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/)